# SpringBoot-Single value to multiple parameter using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

**PostgreSQL Query**

```
select date,count(*) from table1 
where (DATE_PART('day', current_date::timestamp - table1.date::timestamp )) 
<(SELECT value from keyvaluepair where priority='Important')
and priority = 'Important' group by date
order by date
```

I will be calling from api where

```
http://localhost:8080/get/getDates?priority=Important
```

I will be passing as ? in both places as shown

```
select date,count(*) from table1 
    where (DATE_PART('day', current_date::timestamp - table1.date::timestamp)) 
    <(SELECT value from keyvaluepair where priority=?)
    and priority = ? group by date
    order by date
```

I'm getting error like this

```
No value specified for parameter 2.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 2.
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback;
```

In java I'm just getting this query data date and count.

```
public Map<String,Object> getDates(String priority) {
        Map<String,Object> map = new Map<String,Object>();
        List<Object> count = new ArrayList<Object>();
        List<Object> date = new ArrayList<Object>();
        try {

            jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Object[] { priority }, new RowMapper<Object>() {

                @Override
                public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    date.add(rs.getString("date"));
                    count.add(rs.getInt("count"));
                    return null;
                }

            });
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return map;
    }
```

How to give priority once and use it twice in query?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and show us your Java code (and the **real** query string using the parameters)

Comment: The value that you capture in "priority" in the URL will be used to run a query on PostgreSQL. However, the piece of Java code where you perform this operation is where you might need to look into.

If you can, please share that piece of code and see if you can preserve that value when you run 2nd query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.date,count(*) from table1 t1 
where (DATE_PART('day', current_date::timestamp - t1.date::timestamp )) 
<(SELECT value from keyvaluepair k where k.priority=t1.priority)
and t1.priority = 'Important' group by t1.date
order by t1.date
```

This changes in query helped me in resolving error which I had as shown 
**No value specified for parameter 2.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 2.
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback;**
where two column names of table are same and I have to pass value once for all parameters as in link show below

```
http://localhost:8080/get/getDates?priority=Important

select t1.date,count(*) from table1 t1 
    where (DATE_PART('day', current_date::timestamp - t1.date::timestamp )) 
    <(SELECT value from keyvaluepair k where k.priority=t1.priority)
    and t1.priority = ? group by t1.date
    order by t1.date
```

here in this link single **value that is priority Important** is taken to query where it is used for both tables parameter of same column name.